# Python - Referenced packages to be attributes of other packages

Tags: python, import, package, relative-import

How do I make one package reference another package, but make it look like the referenced package belongs to the initial package?

```
package_1
|
|____ __init__.py

package_2
|
|____ __init__.py
|____ module_1.py
```

Inside package_1.__init__.py is

```
# __init__.py
import package_2
```

Now the following calls works fine:

```
>>> import package_1
>>> print package_1
<module <module 'package_1' from  '...\package_1\__init__.pyc'>

>>> from package_1 import package_2
>>> print package_2
<module 'package_2' from '...\package_2\__init__.pyc'>

>>> print package_2.module_1
<module 'package_2.module_1' from '...\package_2\module_1.pyc'>

>>> from package_2 import module_1
>>> print module_1
<module 'package_2.module_1' from '...\package_2\module_1.pyc'>
```

But I want to be able to do this:

```
>>> from package_1.package_2 import module_1
```

But I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "testfile.py", line 15, in <module>
        from package_1.package_2 import module_1
ImportError: No module named package_2
```

The reason I want to do this is because package_2 used to be a subpackage of package_1. Now that package_2 is it's own package, I want to be able to reference it from package_1 to keep the behaviour as it was before.

Comment: I had this question lingering in my mind. And direly need a solution to it. Or else it would mean edit an unknown number of files. But I suspect it has to do with the modules and packages. The dot after the package only looks for modules/packages within that package and not the elements (crude description) of the package.

Comment: Yes I see what you are saying, so I guess I'm trying to trick package_1 into thinking that package_2 is a module or package inside package_1. I don't know how I can create, say a 'package_2.py', and reference the real 'package_2' (since any reference to 'package_2' from package_2.py will point to the current module and not the external package).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `package_2.py` module under `package_1` that simply contains:

```
from package_2 import *
```

If you are using python2 you should add:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

At the top of the file in order to have python3's behaviour.

In this way `package_1.package_2` will be *different* from `package_2`, i.e.:

```
import package_1.package_2
import package_2
print(package_2 is package_1.package2)   #False
```

However all the objects *inside* `package_1.package_2` *are* the same of the external module.

This has the limitations that if you want to import a submodule, and not just something defined in `package_2/__init__.py`'s, you get an `ImportError`. If you want to avoid this you can:

- Use specific `import`s to import all the stuff you need:

  ```
  from package_2 import *
  from package_2 import submodule1, submodule2, subpackage3
  ```
- Add an `_all.py` module under `package_2` that imports all the stuff you want exposed and import from that

Surely `*`-imports are often avoided, but *in this case*, it seems like the only solution to your problem that doesn't required hacking the importing mechanism.

If you really hate this the other way I can think of is to write a custom importer using importing hooks, but this would require quite a bit of work to get it right.

Also, since `package_2` is now its own package you should probably consider deprecating the old way of importing in order to be able to remove this "hack" in some future release. Probably it's not worth it to spend too much time writing an import hook if you are going to get rid of it in the future anyway.

---

Note that the `from` import:

```
from package_1.package_2 import module1
```

**Requires** you to actually provide a `package_1.package_2` module or subpackage.

The `import`s of the form:

```
from X.Y.Z import something
```

First import `X`, then the importer will search for a file called `Y.py` under the `X` directory. Then it will search a `Z.py` file under `X/Y` or the directory `X/Y/Z` finally, if `something` is found in the imported `Z` module it is simply placed in the scope, otherwise `something` is a module that is imported.

However this last step, checking whether `something` already exists in `Z`, is *only* performed when all of `X`, `Y` and `Z` were completely imported. In your use case:

```
from package_1.package_2 import module1
```

You simply *cannot* have `package_2` simply defined inside `package_1`.

Comment: I know this would seem like it would work (and was my first thought initially). But as in my above comment, any reference to 'package_2' from 'package_2.py' will point to the current module and not the external package

Comment: @mtookie Can you clarify what do you mean by "reference"?

Comment: @mtookie Oh, I think I see what you mean. The problem with this approach is that it requires the real `package_2` to explicitly import its submodules. You can either change the `*`-import to explicitly import those, or add a `package_2/all.py` that imports all the stuff you want and import from that.

Comment: Any time you use the variable name `package_2` (as in `from package_2 import *`), that variable name will be associated with the current module (`package_2.py`) and not the package named `package_2` (I think).

Comment: @mtookie No. `from package_2 import *` is an *absolute* import and so it works fine. It has its limitations (I've edited my answer), but not what you were thinking about. *Especially* in python3 where there is no ambiguity between relative and absolute imports.

Comment: You may need to try your solution to see what I mean. Try creating a basic file called `package_2.py`, then add two lines `import package_2` and `print package_2`. The module that gets printed is the package_2.py you created. However I need imports to `package_2` inside `package_2.py` to reference external packages of the same name. Might be confusing, so I suggest trying an example

Comment: @mtookie Try to add `from __future__ import absolute_import` right at the top of the `package_2.py`. In python2 that's the *only* case when the `import` is relative although you really want an absolute import. Using the `__future__` feature you can change the behaviour to that of python3 that will *not* import `package_2.py` but the package you wanted. FYI: I just tested this with both python2 and 3 and `from package_1.package_2 import module1` *does* work (taking into account the limitations in the answer).